# Can I take home made food in my luggage on flight?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, transportation

This is domestic flight. Since I am traveling first time, I am making sure. And if Airport authority disallow me carrying food then, Will they make me discard it in bin?

Comment: Domestic flight in which country? (This may be important - also, few posters wil know the regulations of *all* countries).

Comment: Checked (hold) or cabin baggage?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, food items are okay if they are properly packed and sealed.  If for any reason the item is not allowed, it will be confiscated at the security checkpoint and then destroyed by the authorities.

The reason food items must be securely packed/sealed is to prevent any issues during flight with leaky items.

In worse case scenarios - your food may contain elements that can trigger allergic reactions in passengers - for example, some people are extremely sensitive to nuts and even the *dust* can trigger an allergic reaction.

Therefore, airlines are cautious of allowing food on board.

However, as long as it is securely packed you should not have an issue.

Answer (score 1):

From my own experience, I have always been able to take food onto any flight, domestic and international.  I've flown around NZ, Australia, Asia, Europe and the USA.  I've only ever seen fine print for some budget airlines that say you are not allowed to bring food onto the plane for consumption (more to do with them forcing you to buy their food).  So if you are not planning to eat it on the plane you should be fine, but if you are, just check which airline you are flying.

Having said that, if you put it in your bag, they never check. I've brought food like sealed packets (penuts, crisps, crackers, cookies etc) as well as hot food such as McDonalds, KFC, Sushi, Sandwiches.

So long as you don't bring in food/drinks from outside airport security that contain too much liquid.  Aside from that, most foods should be fine.

P.S. almost all airlines will not allow you to drink alcohol that was not purchased on the plane.  Water and other soft drinks are usually fine.